# Is there any limitation of sched_deadline in rt-kernel under Ubuntu?

Tags: kernel

I'm running an open source FFTW module in  realtime kernel with schedule_deadline where I need a deadline of 0.5 ms. I noticed no difference in any behavior as specified by Ubuntu (image attached below).

1 . There are some peaks at beginning. What's the reason?
2 . "Ubuntu RT is deterministic" -> then why is it taking middle peaks?
3 . Will assigning the deadline takes some time, so only is that peak?

image_sched_deadline:

[[image: image_sched_deadline]][[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SAuRl.png)